# Integration of $\int_{0}^{1.7}[x^2]dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

so we have got this problem $$I=\int_{0}^{1.7}[x^2]dx$$ where $[f(x)]$ is under greatest integer function so i thuought of this possible solution
$$I=\int_{0}^{1.7}[x^2]dx =\int_{0}^{1}[x^2]dx+\int_{1}^{1.4}[x^2]dx+\int_{1.4}^{1.7}[x^2]dx$$
$$=0+(1.4-1)+2*(1.7-1.4)=1$$ which i think is very much incorrect , how to do this integration?

Comment: Why would you go to 1.4?

Comment: Do you mean ceiling function?

Comment: mainly because $1.4*1.4=1.94$ and when 1.94 takes inside greatest integer function will become 1 that was simplest  closed integer i could think of that would make up for $x^2 < 2$ to break integreation

Comment: Why don't you use $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ etc.?

Comment: You do not need to split integrals up at rational values. It is perfectly okay to integrate from 1 to $\sqrt{2}$. (Which will give the correct answer)

Comment: greating integer function return for fraction value like $1.56$ as 1 or $2.999$ as $2$ it basically gives out greatest integer value before that number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In general, to integrate this function you should figure out *exactly* where $[x^2]$ changes values in the interval you're integrating over and break up the integral at these locations. For the interval $[0,1.7]$, the only values the integrand takes are $0$, $1$, and $2$ (why?), and you still need to figure out at which value $a$ is it true that $[a^2] = 2$ but $[x^2] < 2$ for $0\leq x < a$. (You'll find that $a$ is irrational.) Once you recognize what $a$ is, rewrite the integral in a similar manner to the one in your solution as

$$
I = \int_0^1 0 \,dx + \int_1^a 1 \,dx + \int_a^{1.7} 2\,dx
  = 0 + a-1 + 2(1.7-a).
$$

Comment: and a is $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Tesla: Correct!